# Google speech to text API Callback

Tags: google-speech-api

When the conversion from Speech to text starts it uses server time for the entire transcription. So let's say if Audio is 4 minutes long then server will run for 4 minutes.

so is there any way where transcription starts and my server stops, after the successful transcription API posts message to a URL from where I will come to know that Audio transcription has been successfully completed.